# 500 encoding error when user copies and pastes 'unusual' characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, encoding

I was just testing my site and I copied and pasted some text from another page into my user profile. When I clicked `update`, I got a 500:

```
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: U+201C from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1
```

The offending character turned out to be a simple `"`. What should I do to make my form less vulnerable to copying and pasting, which I imagine many users in my situation will be doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real error here is that you're not using UTF-8 somewhere, probably in your database. Make sure your database is UTF-8 encoded for maximum compatibility. (Also, if for some reason you've setup Rails to use something other than UTF-8 for encoding, I'd *highly* recommend using UTF-8 instead, there's very rarely any good reason not to.)

Comment: Andrew, how can I check a local mysql database and a Heroku database for their encoding settings?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/internationalization-localization.html. Heroku is probably UTF-8 by default.